# Notice: _usort_terms_by_ID is deprecated since version 4.7.0! Use wp_list_sort instead

Tags: plugin-development

I have updated my **wordpress** version from **4.6.1** to **4.7.0**, but after updating i am getting this error message, when i add or edit any product in **woocommerce**:

> Notice: _usort_terms_by_ID is deprecated since version 4.7.0! Use
>   wp_list_sort instead. in /wp-includes/functions.php on line 3783

But after searching whole files there is no function like that, so how i can fix this issue..

Comment: did you try searching inside the all themes and plugin folder ?

Comment: @GovindKumar yes i have tried to search but not found this function.

Comment: it is inside the woocommerce https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/master/includes/wc-product-functions.php#L250

Comment: @GovindKumar Thanks, found that and after replace by wp_list_sort  it works perfect.

Comment: I posted a workaround [here in #12525](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/12525#issuecomment-265405727) for WP 4.7+ and older versions, that has just been patched.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function `wp_list_sort()` [has been introduced in WordPress 4.7](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/37128). It wasn't available before. That's probably why your plugin isn't using it.

The function `_usort_terms_by_ID()` is still working, and it is actually much faster than `wp_list_sort()`. Which makes it hard to understand why it has been deprecated. *But* in your own code keep in mind that functions starting with an undercore (`_`) are meant to be private in WordPress. You should not use them in your code, at least not directly.

The real issue here is that you can see notices. These are *informal*, they should be visible for you only, not for your visitors. If that site is public, make sure you turn the debug mode off in your `wp-config.php`.

[WooCommerce has a fix already](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/issues/12525); you will get that with the next update, so just keep your site up to date, and you are fine.